# Is it possible to configure the csproj so that it overrides the --self-contained flag for dotnet publish?

Tags: .net, publish, csproj

On my build server, the dotnet publish command is called on the solution file with the self-contained argument set to true. However, I would like to have one of my project in the solution to always run with self-contained set to false as I want to exclude the dotnet runtimes in the publish output for this project. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The framework dependent output is generated in the bin folder as a step, so instead of finding a way to override that flag, you just copy what you want from the right folder.

Answer (score 9):

you can edit your csproj file to mark the flag to allow overriding in the static part of your project and then set it to `False`:

```
<Project TreatAsLocalProperty="SelfContained">
  <PropertyGroup>
    …
    <SelfContained>False</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
  …
</Project>
```